# Unique Integers From Array List

Tags: java, arraylist, unique

I am having problems with making a method that will return distinct integers of the array list. I really want to do it with removing the duplicates and then just display the array list. I cannot figure out what is the problem. When I test it out this is the output I get: [3, 11, 33, 10]

This is my code

```
package getUniques;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Uniques {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> getUniques( ArrayList<Integer> list ){
        int i = 0;
        while(i < list.size() - 1){

            for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++){

                if (list.get(i) == list.get(j))
                    list.remove(i);
            }
            i++;
        }

        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(3);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(11);
        list.add(22);
        list.add(33);
        list.add(22);
        list.add(10);
        System.out.println(getUniques(list));
    }

}
```

Comment: Gotta sleep, but put the `int` values as `Integer` in a `Set`. Then check if the `int` is in the `Set`. If it is, remove the value. Best to use a `for...next` loop (i.e. an `Iterator`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few problems.  Here's fixes for your existing code:

First you are removing the wrong index.  You've identified the element at `j` as the duplicate; remove it instead of the element at `i`.

```
list.remove(j);  // j not i
```

Next, you are removing *all* elements that are the same, and you aren't leaving the "original".  To fix this, only test (and remove) those that are past `i` in the loop.

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++){  // Start at i + 1, not 0.
```

Then you'll need to retry your `j` index once you've removed it, because the rest of the elements have been shifted backwards 1 spot.  Instead of

```
if (list.get(i) == list.get(j))
    list.remove(i);
```

Try

```
if (list.get(i) == list.get(j))
{
    list.remove(j);
    j--;  // Try this j again next loop, once it's incremented again.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also get unique values by using [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). Insert the values in a `Set` and then put it back into an `ArrayList` like `new ArrayList(theSet);`

Comment: That would remove the order. I don't know if that is acceptable or not.

Comment: @owlstead then you can use a sortedset instead.

Comment: You can also look at `LinkedHashSet` to maintain the insertion order.

Comment: @tieTYT only if the natural ordering is identical to the order in the `List`

Answer (score 1):

Changing the list as you iterate over it is always going to cause pain!
Say you remove item 3 (so the old 4th becomes the new 3) - then you do i++, so you are effectively skipping the "old 4th" element.

You can  skip the `i++` if you removed the item to get back on track, but a some other
    solutions:

1. Use a Set or similar in the first place so you can't get duplicates.
2. Use a second list to hold the values (or indexes) of items you want
   to remove (if using indexes, you can remove them highest to lowest
   else you end up with the same issue: delete index 1, index 4 is now
   index 3...)
3. Flip your search so you are going back towards 0, same principal
   applies. You can remove high indexes without impacting lower ones.
4. Make your outer loop use an iterator so you can use the remove operation.

Answer (score 0):

To remove items while iterating, you have to use an iterator, as it guarantees the order:

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
int i = 0;
List<Integer> listCopy = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    i++;
    Integer value = iterator.next()
    for (int j = i; j < listCopy.size(); j++){
        if (value.equals(listCopy.get(j))) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

However, in this case, as you need to iterate twice through the same list, it's not the best solution. It might be faster putting everything into a sorted Set, as Set removes duplicates on its own.

Comment: The i++ was copy/paste issue, sorry. But `iterator.remove()` removes the current item only.

Comment: this won't work... removes all... and you are using `==` with Integer.. -1 until fix

Comment: You are right, I eddited to have something functional until I think something better.

Comment: In the end my intention was to show how to remove using an iterator, but it's not the best solution for this specific case as it is iterating twice through the same list.